# Why is $\iota$ injectif?

Tags: field-theory

Let $K$ a field. An extension $L$ of $K$ is a field $L$ and a morphism of ring $\iota: K\hookrightarrow L$. And the it says that such a morphism is alway injectif because since $$1_K\overset{\iota}{\mapsto} 1_L$$
$\ker \iota\neq K$ and thus $\ker\iota=\{0\}$.

**Question :** Why the fact that $\ker\iota\neq K\implies \ker\iota=\{0\}$ ?

Comment: Because the kernel is an ideal.

Comment: I'm not sure ti understand. If the kernal is an ideal, why it imply that $\ker \iota\neq K\implies \ker\iota =\{0\}$. It's probably a very simple result of ring theorey, but I don't find any theorem like that in my book.

Comment: Let $I$ be a nontrivial ideal in a field $K$. It contains an element $x \neq 0$. What can you conclude?

Comment: I think I do. Thank you.